# Search bar by using LinQ

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to show the results only that match the user input, but this code will show the whole table, do you know what is the problem? For example, if the user enters "233442" id it will only show him the users that their id "233442". The user could search by id, name, or username.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SearchBarLinQ
{
    public partial class SearchBarLinQ : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var st = (from s in db.SearchTable2s where s.ID == int.Parse(TxtID.Text) select s).First();
            TxtName.Text = st.Name;
            TxtUsername.Text = st.Username;

            LoadData();

        }
        void LoadData()
        {
            var st = from s in db.SearchTable2s select s;
            GridView1.DataSource = st;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function btnsearch_Click is processing the search, but the value you found is not displayed. You need to assign the value found to the data source of girdview.
Refer to the sample code(Customize the param object of the LoadData function to be compatible with the view):

```
 protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var st = (from s in db.SearchTable2s where s.ID == int.Parse(TxtID.Text) select s).First();
            TxtName.Text = st.Name;
            TxtUsername.Text = st.Username;

            LoadData(st);

        }
void LoadData(object param)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = param;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```